# custom save query for Spring Data (Hibernate JPA)

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have two entities:

**WeeklyBoxOffice.java**

```
 @Entity
    public class WeeklyBoxOffice {

    @NotNull
    private String country;

    @Id
    @NotNull
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    private long weeklyGross;

    @NotNull
    private double weeklyChange;

    @OneToOne//(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL )
    @JoinColumn(name = "name")
    private Movie movie;
    }
```

**Movie.java**

```
 @Entity
    @Table(name = "movies")
    public class Movie {

    @Id
    @NotNull
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    private String imageLink;
    }
```

And following repository:

```
public interface WeeklyBoxOfficeRepository extends   
CrudRepository<WeeklyBoxOffice, String> {
    Iterable<WeeklyBoxOffice> findByCountryOrderByWeeklyGrossDesc(String country);
}
```

Existing find method works like left join, which is exactly what I need. But how to save WeeklyBoxOffice object without saving movie object? I don't really the idea of creating WeeklyBoxOfficeLite. Now it gives an exception

> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException:
>   org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an
>   unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before
>   flushing : entity.WeeklyBoxOffice.movie -> entity.Movie; nested
>   exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an
>   unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before
>   flushing : entity.WeeklyBoxOffice.movie -> entity.Movie ... Caused by:
>   org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an
>   unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before
>   flushing : WeeklyBoxOffice.movie -> entity.Movie

Is it possible to use somehow NativeQuery for save method to ignore nested Movie object?

Comment: can you show your persist or merge method ???

Comment: Using default CRUD repository impl

Comment: What data/json are you sending to your API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you removed the cascade from the association with `movie`, then you should not get this error, imho...

But anyway maybe this workaround can help...

```
public class WeeklyBoxOfficeService {

    @Autoware
    private WeeklyBoxOfficeRepo repo;

    public WeeklyBoxOffice saveWithoutMovie(WeeklyBoxOffice weeklyBoxOffice) {

        weeklyBoxOffice.setMovie(null); // 'unlink' movie from BO
        repo.save(weeklyBoxOffice); // save BO without movie
    }  
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/weeklyBoxOffice")
public class WeeklyBoxOfficeController {

    @Autoware
    private WeeklyBoxOfficeService service;

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<?> saveWithoutMovie(@RequestBody WeeklyBoxOffice weeklyBoxOffice) {

        WeeklyBoxOffice result = service.saveWithoutMovie(weeklyBoxOffice);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply set to `null` the `movie` field before invoking the `save()` operation ? 
In this way, Hibernate will ignore it during the flush.

Comment: I guess the field is null by default, as I'm constructing this object from JSON with @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true) ?

Comment: If you have this Hibernate error message, it means that is not null. Check it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are also sending JSON of Movie with WeeklyBoxOffice JSON like

```
{
    "country": "xxxxxx",
    "name": "xxxxxxxx",
    "weeklyGross": "xxxxx",
    "weeklyChange": "xxxxxx",
    "movie": {
        "name": "xxxxxx",
        "imageLink": "xxxxx"
    }
}
```

So you have to first create a **MovieRepository** and save movie using this repository and then save **WeeklyBoxOffice** using **WeeklyBoxOfficeRepository** like this

```
    @Autowired
    WeeklyBoxOfficeRepository weeklyBoxOfficeRepository;
    @Autowired
    MovieRepository movieRepository;
    public WeeklyBoxOffice saveWeeklyBoxOffice(WeeklyBoxOffice weeklyBoxOffice) {
           movieRepository.save(weeklyBoxOffice.getMovie());
           return weeklyBoxOfficeRepository.save(weeklyBoxOffice);
    }
```

Other solution, you can use `CascadeType.All` for saving this JSON using only one line

```
weeklyBoxOfficeRepository.save(weeklyBoxOffice);
```

this line will automatically save and will also assign movie name(id) to **weeklyBoxOffice**.